# Add a vertical line based on click

Tags: r, ironpython, spotfire

I have a Spotfire visualization plot (scatter plot) when a user clicks on any point on the plot, how can I put a vertical line there and export corresponding x-axis value?

Guessing I should script in R or Ironpython?

Comment: @rawr OP is asking about Spotfire, no need to downvote if that was you. this question makes sense in the context of Spotfire, which supports R, thus the tag.

Comment: @c.Parsi are you okay with having the user select a point and then clicking a button to draw the line? I know that's not ideal but I'm not sure it's possible with a "normal" scatterplot. I have some esoteric experimental ideas that I can throw at you but I want to verify them tomorrow before I give you bad info. let me know if the button works or not in the meantime? cheers!

Comment: @niko no i don't downvote

Comment: @niko: Yes that would be fine,